# Cannot get value from Global State(Redux)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, global-state

I am having trouble creating this shared component in my project.
This is simplified version of its code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    platform: state.device.get('platform') //defines if iOS or Android
  };
}

export function SharedView({ theme, ...props }) {
  return <View {...props}>{theme}</View>;
}

export default SharedView(
  connect(mapStateToProps, null)
);
```

As I try to add `console.log` or `alert` inside of my `mapStateToProps` I get nothing and it seems I can not see it from my `SharedView`. I know I could rewrite it to class `SharedView extends Component { ...`, but for certain reasons I need to keep the format.

Any ideas how to get this global state value?

Comment: Try to use this: `export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(SharedView)`, not: `SharedView(connect...)`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but still the same situation in this syntax.

Comment: Check in yours `mapStateToProps`, `state` is undefined?

Comment: Why `export function SharedView`? No need to export this function. Try to remove the export there and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: mapStateToProps is fully ignored for some reason, I cannot console log it or alert it, or even debugger jumps imidiatelly to export function StatsBar()

Comment: @MindaugasJačionis use `class SharedView extends React.Component {}` and dont export this. Code will work when u returned `export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(SharedView)`

Comment: Yea, I know I can do this, I am just not sure what to do with my index then. These shared components are in shared folder where index.js exports them and then I can include them in other files using import {SharedElement} from '../shared'


With this class approach I kinda can not add it like that, which ruins consistency. For time being I already did as you suggested, but will need to look more into this later. :)

Answer (score 2):

`connect` is a higher order function - your component is supposed to be wrapped in it not the other way around.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SharedView);
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but still the same situation in this syntax.

Comment: Did you wrap your app component in a Provider component?